# CakePHP is my logic correct?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have this system: One resale has many servers, and one server belongs to a resale.

So, I'm using `ResalesController` to save a Server, right? then should I call `Server` Model method to save or `Resale` Model method?

Actually I use the `Resale` Model, `SaveServer` method that calls `$this->Server->save();`..

Comment: What is your actual question? You can save associated models recursively using `saveAll` if they are correctly linked - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

Comment: Which Model should I call from controller for save a Server that belongs to a Resale? Model `Resale` or `Server`? assuming that I'm using the `ResalesController`.

Comment: **Read the manual.** You can use whatever model you want, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you need save a server and at the same time, associate this with a resale, you can:

**ServersController.php**

```
public function add() {
 if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
  /* CakePHP automagically take the params from request, and associate models */
  $this->Server->save($this->request->data);
 }
}
```

But, you need to set in `$this->request->data` a key for ID of the resale.

Your users can select the the resales in the same form that they select server:

```
<select name="data[Server][resale_id]" id="ServerResaleId">
 <option value="1">Resale 1</option>
 <option value="2">Resale 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Good point.. but, actually the Controller that renders the form is `ResalesController`, is the same code or that should call `$this->Resale->save($this->request->data);`or doesn't matter?